# How to handle onKeyUp event in ReactJS form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a generic JavaScript function as follows
home.js

```
function numericOdds(e) {
  var valid = /^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,1}$/
  var number = /^[1-9]{1}$ | ^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/
  var lastValid = '';
  var n;
  console.log('Key pressed : ', event.keyCode)
  if (!valid.test(e.target.value)) {
    console.log('target :' + e.target.value);
    n = e.target.value.match(number);
    console.log('n :' + n)
    e.target.value = n ? n : lastValid;
  } else {
    lastValid = e.target.value;
    console.log('lastValid :' + lastValid)
  }
}
```

It works as expected when I use this in a generic HTML form

```
<input type="number" name="add-numberOdds" onkeyup="numericOdds(event);" min="1" max="99" required="" id="id_add-numberOdds">
```

The form fails to load, when I try to use this function in a React Form Component. Here is the React Form Component

```
<Form.Group>
  <Form.Control type="number" name="add-numberOdds"
    onKeyUp={numericOdds(event)} min="1" max="99"
    required="" id="id_add-numberOdds" />
</Form.Group>
```

The Console log is as follows:

```
Key pressed : undefined
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at numericOdds (home.js:10)
```

I am getting this error at the time of the form rendering. I think I may be binding this function to the component incorrectly. The function is a generic function and is used elsewhere also. Therefore I don't want to define it inside the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently calling the `numericOdds` function during rendering, as opposed to when the event happens. `onKeyUp` needs to be a function:

```
onKeyUp={numericOdds}
```